# PHP Divide Array into two arrays using array value

Tags: php, arrays, search, split

I have a PHP array like below:

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => 16
        [1] => 17
        [2] => 18
        [3] => 23
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 6
        [6] => 14
        [7] => 22
    )
```

I need two split this array in to two arrays by 23 value it will be like below:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 16
        [1] => 17
        [2] => 18
    )

 Array(
        [0] => 23
        [1] => 7
        [2] => 6
        [3] => 14
        [4] => 22
    )
```

Can any one know how to do this with PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `23` in the code below is hardcoded, and the original array will be split only if the `23` value found in the source array:

```
$arr = array(16, 17, 18, 23, 7, 6, 14, 22);
$split_by = array_search(23, $arr);

if ($split_by) {
    $first = array_slice($arr, 0, $split_by);
    $second = array_slice($arr, $split_by);

    var_dump($first, $second);
}
```

http://ideone.com/BPn7t

or

```
$arr = array(16, 17, 18, 23, 7, 6, 14, 22);
$split_by = array_search(23, $arr);

if ($split_by) {
    $first = array_slice($arr, 0, $split_by + 1);
    $second = array_slice($arr, $split_by + 1);

    var_dump($first, $second);
}
```

if you need to left the found value in the first array

Comment: @smith bandara: added second example